# push array into array in specific format

Tags: php, arrays, push

I have this array structure named $params

```
Array
(
    [PLANT_RA] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [SIGN] => I
                    [OPTION] => EQ
                    [LOW] => 6104
                    [HIGH] => 
                )
        )

    [STGE_LOC_RA] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [SIGN] => I
                    [OPTION] => EQ
                    [LOW] => 5700
                    [HIGH] => 
                )
        )

    [BATCH_RA] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [SIGN] => I
                    [OPTION] => NE
                    [LOW] => 
                    [HIGH] => 
                )
        )
)
```

which is created:

```
$parms2 = array(
    'PLANT_RA' => array(array(
        'SIGN' => "I",
        'OPTION' => getOption($_GET['PLANT_RA-low'], $_GET['PLANT_RA-high']),
        'LOW' => $_GET['PLANT_RA-low'],
        'HIGH' => $_GET['PLANT_RA-high']
    )),

    'STGE_LOC_RA' => array(array(
        'SIGN' => "I",
        'OPTION' => getOption($_GET['STGE_LOC_RA-low'], $_GET['STGE_LOC_RA-high']),
        'LOW' => $_GET['STGE_LOC_RA-low'],
        'HIGH' => $_GET['STGE_LOC_RA-high']
    )),

    'BATCH_RA' => array(array(
        'SIGN' => "I",
        'OPTION' => getOption($_GET['BATCH_RA-low'], $_GET['BATCH_RA-high']),
        'LOW' => $_GET['BATCH_RA-low'],
        'HIGH' => $_GET['BATCH_RA-high']
    ))
)
```

However, now for my purposes I need to change it and use it via array_push(),
so I can declare empty array:

```
$parms2 = array();
```

and now when I push it in:

```
if (isset($_GET['PLANT_RA-low'])) {
    $storage_array = array('PLANT_RA' => array(
        'SIGN' => "I",
        'OPTION' => getOption($_GET['PLANT_RA-low'], $_GET['PLANT_RA-high']),
        'LOW' => $_GET['PLANT_RA-low'],
        'HIGH' => $_GET['PLANT_RA-high']
    ));
    array_push($parms, $storage_array);
}
if (isset($_GET['STGE_LOC_RA-low'])) {
    $storage_array = array('STGE_LOC_RA' => array(
        'SIGN' => "I",
        'OPTION' => getOption($_GET['STGE_LOC_RA-low'], $_GET['STGE_LOC_RA-high']),
        'LOW' => $_GET['STGE_LOC_RA-low'],
        'HIGH' => $_GET['STGE_LOC_RA-high']
    ));
    array_push($parms, $storage_array);
}
if (isset($_GET['BATCH_RA-low'])) {
    $batch_array = array('BATCH_RA' => array(
        'SIGN' => "I",
        'OPTION' => getOption($_GET['BATCH_RA-low'], $_GET['BATCH_RA-high']),
        'LOW' => $_GET['BATCH_RA-low'],
        'HIGH' => $_GET['BATCH_RA-high']
    ));
    array_push($parms, $batch_array);
}
```

then it has not correct format which is refused by SAPNWRFC:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PLANT_RA] => Array
                (
                    [SIGN] => I
                    [OPTION] => EQ
                    [LOW] => 6104
                    [HIGH] => 
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [STGE_LOC_RA] => Array
                (
                    [SIGN] => I
                    [OPTION] => EQ
                    [LOW] => 5700
                    [HIGH] => 
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [BATCH_RA] => Array
                (
                    [SIGN] => I
                    [OPTION] => NE
                    [LOW] => 
                    [HIGH] => 
                )
        )
)
```

can you please guide me how do I push (in what format) so I have the EXACT same output of the $params array at the end?

Comment: You probably want [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) instead of array_push.

Comment: Why array_push in the first place? You _know_ the keys you want to create the new array entries under - so, assign them directly? `$parms2['PLANT_RA'] = …`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end all this code can be reduced to:

```
$parms = [];
$keys = ['PLANT_RA', 'STGE_LOC_RA', 'BATCH_RA'];
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    if (isset($_GET[$key . '-low'])) {
        $parms[$key] = [
            [
                'SIGN' => "I",
                'OPTION' => getOption($_GET[$key . '-low'], $_GET[$key . '-high']),
                'LOW' => $_GET[$key . '-low'],
                'HIGH' => $_GET[$key . '-high']
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```